# Navigating to 'Album/{index}' destination always passes index as 0 instead of the selected list item index

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

> Problem Description:
> I'm encountering an issue with the index value when navigating from the list to the 'Album/{index}' route in my Jetpack Compose application.

> Expected Behavior:
> I expect the index value to be passed correctly when navigating to the 'Album/{index}' route. Each item in the list should correspond to its respective index, and the correct index should be logged when navigating.

```
@Composable
    fun nav()
    {
        lateinit var obj: playerviewmodel
        val navController = rememberNavController()
        NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "list")
        {
            composable(route = "Album/{index}")
            {
                backStackEntry ->
                val index = backStackEntry.arguments?.getInt("index") ?:0

                Log.d("ViewModel", "dummy: $index")
                obj = viewModel(factory = factory(index))
                val stateview = (obj as? playerviewmodel)?.ret()
                Space(img = img, index = index, text = text1, sub = text2, stateview = obj)
            }
            composable(route = "list")
            {
                view(nav = navController, image = img, text = text1, sub = text2)
            }
        }
    }
}
@Composable
fun Listitem(
    img: Array<Int>,
    title: Array<String>,
    sub: Array<String>,
    nav: NavController,
    index: Int
)
{
    var objects by Delegates.notNull<Int>()
    Card(modifier = Modifier.clickable {
        nav.navigate("Album/$index")
        Log.d("list", "index: $index")
    }) {
        Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
            Image(painter = painterResource(id = img[index]), contentDescription = "", modifier = Modifier
                .padding(8.dp)
                .weight(.2f)
                .size(68.dp))
            Column(modifier = Modifier.weight(.8f)) {
                Text(text = title[index], style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold, modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp))
                Text(text = sub[index], fontWeight = FontWeight.Thin, style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelMedium, modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 8.dp))
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun view(
    nav: NavController,
    image: Array<Int>,
    text: Array<String>,
    sub: Array<String>
)
{
    LazyColumn(content = {
        val itemcount = image.size
        items(itemcount){
              Listitem(img = image, title = text, sub = sub, nav = nav, index = it)
        }
    })
}
```

> Attempted Solutions:
> I've tried adding log statements to trace the value of the index at different stages. While the index is correct when clicking on items in the list, it seems to revert to 0 when navigating to the 'Album/{index}' route.

> Additional Context:
> I'm using Jetpack Compose for UI, and the navigation is handled with a NavController.
> For each item click in a Jetpack Compose list, the correct index is logged, but when navigating to the 'Album/{index}' route, the index value is consistently reset to 0. Seeking assistance to understand and resolve this issue in the navigation flow.

Comment: Did you [read the documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nav-with-args) that states that all arguments default to Strings? Is there a reason you don't specify an `IntType` if you want the index as an int?

Comment: You need to define the argument type that you are passing to the screen. Add the arguments key in the "Album/{index}" composable and it should work fine.